# Rewrite except with ! not work in htaccess Apache 2.4.6

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Usually use the code below to redirect everything but a specific address to another domain.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/adminpanel/$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.somesite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But now, I stopped working with Apache 2.4.6. Now, Apache rewrite every request to https://www.somesite.com/

Comment: Add the variable to the query string of the rewrite target, that should be an easy way to check what it actually contains.

Comment: @CBroe, sorry I don't understand

Comment: `https://www.somesite.com/$1?foo=%{REQUEST_URI}`, and then check whether that variable actually contains what you expected or not via the browser address bar or network panel ...